Exercise 9.6 in Algebraic Combinatorics by Stanley
Exercise 6 in chapter 9 of Algebraic Combinatorics by Stanley: Let $G$ be a finite graph on $p$ vertices with Laplacian matrix $L(G)$. Let $G'$ be obtained from $G$ by adding a new vertex $v$ and connecting it to each vertex of $G$ (so we have $p$ new edges). Express $\kappa(G')$ (the number of spanning trees of $G'$) in terms of the eigenvalues $\mu_1, \dots, \mu_p$ of $L(G)$.
Clearly, $L(G')$ is just $L(G)$ with a row of $-1$'s and column of $-1$'s below and to the right of the submatrix $L(G)$, respectively, with an additional diagonal element $p$ in the bottom right corner of the matrix, since the added vertex $v$ has degree $p$. Then, by the Matrix-Tree theorem, $\kappa(G') = \det(L(G)) = \mu_1 \dots \mu_p$. However, this inspired the question: if we had only connected $v$ with a select subset of the original $p$ matrices to get some new graph $H$, then we would still get that $\kappa(H) = \det(L(G)) = \kappa(G')$. Thus, even if $v$ was an isolated vertex, we would still have the same number of spanning trees, but this is clearly wrong, as no spanning trees would exist in this case.

The degree of every old vertex increases by one, so $$L(G') = \begin{bmatrix} L(G) + I & -u \\ -u^T & p \end{bmatrix}$$ where $u$ is the column of ones. This gives $\kappa(G') = \det(L(G) + I) = \prod_i (1 + \mu_i)$.
